# Use SHGetKnownFolderPath in path of CreateProcess to run program

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, constants, wchar-t

I am trying to use the function SHGetKnownFolderPath() that gets the directory of the user's localappdata and convert the PWSTR (which is a wchar_t*) into a LPCSTR (which is a const char*) then add the program to the LPCSTR to so it can be used in CreateProcess.

I figured how to use SHGetKnownFolderPath and print the path to the console using printf(%ls%, path) and figured out how to use CreateProcess to execute an .exe file, but I don't know how to make PWSTR into a const char* and include the program I want to be executed into that const char*.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <shlobj_core.h>
#include <string>
#include <KnownFolders.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main () {
    //SHGetKnownFolderPath function
    PWSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT path_here = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &path);

    //CreateProcess funtion
    STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    const char* execute = //Want to have path_here plus another folder and an .exe program.
    BOOL create = CreateProcess(execute, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);
.......................
    }
```

I wouldn't say I know a lot about coding and there is probably something important I don't know about yet. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

I think it would be more helpful if I showed this other part of my code. The following code is right after the code I've written above:

```
if (create){
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
 }
```

Comment: This would be far easier using wchar_t all around rather than performing any conversion. You can have a wide character string literal by prefixing it with L, as in L"my_program.exe". You can then use swprintf instead of sprintf to combine the results of the SHGetKnownFolderPath with the literal, or use std::wstring for the same purpose and then feed the full executable path to CreateProcess.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir "*then feed the full executable path to CreateProcess*" - you mean `CreateProcessW()`. The fact that the OP needs to convert to `char` means the project is not configured for Unicode and thus `CreateProcess()` is mapping to `CreateProcessA()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert to `char` at all. `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` returns a Unicode string. Use `CreateProcessW()` explicitly so you can pass it a Unicode string:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <shlobj_core.h>
#include <string>
#include <KnownFolders.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main ()
{
    PWSTR path = NULL;
    HRESULT hres = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, 0, NULL, &path);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))
    {
        STARTUPINFOW info = { sizeof(STARTUPINFOW) };
        PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
        std::wstring execute = std::wstring(path) + L"\\folder\\program.exe";
        CoTaskMemFree(path);
        BOOL create = CreateProcessW(&execute[0], NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);
        // ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got a new error (C2664): cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'LPCWSTR'. This error happens when I have `NULL` in `CreateProcessW(NULL &execute[0]...` How would I go about solving that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @WolfZwiener Certainly you should be able to figure out what's wrong with `CreateProcessW(NULL &execute[0]...`? The first parameter to `CreateProcessW` is a pointer to a Unicode string, so how do you fix that so it's a pointer to a Unicode string? (It's just a typographical error.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Oh yeah you're right, I got the program to work now. Thanks a lot!